# Mac Image capture driver matching to scanner

Tags: macos, driver, matching, capture

I can't match ICA driver to scanner device on Ventura, log messages after connecting the scanner:

```
icdd                  default            Device DB | Creating local devices icdd
<Missing Description> default Sandbox: icdd(549) allow file-read-data /Library/Image Capture/Devices kernel
<Missing Description> default Sandbox: icdd(549) allow file-read-data /Library/Image Capture/Devices/AbcTr.app/Contents/Resources/DeviceMatchingInfo.plist kernel
<Missing Description> default Sandbox: icdd(549) allow file-read-data /Library/Image Capture/Devices/AbcTr.app/Contents/Resources/DeviceInfo.plist kernel
icdd                  default            Device DB | Creating bonjour devices icdd
<Missing Description> default Sandbox: icdd(549) allow file-read-data /Library/Image Capture/Devices kernel
<Missing Description> default Sandbox: icdd(549) allow file-read-data /Library/Image Capture/Devices/AbcTr.app/Contents/Resources/DeviceMatchingInfo.plist kernel
icdd                  default       =>  [Matching] | [ 0x00,0x00,0x00 ] icdd
icdd                  default                Added | 0x10000007 - [USB][   Travel Pro ] ( 0, 0, 0) @ 0x2400000 | icdd
icdd                  default           Autolaunch | 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000030 => (null) icdd
ccid                  error   Failed to find AppleUSBAlternateServiceRegistryID.  com.apple.ifdreader
```

Vendor and product IDS are defined in DeviceMatchingInfo.plist:

```
    <key>usb</key>
    <dict>
        <key>IOUSBDevice</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>Product Identification</key>
                <string>Travel Pro</string>
                <key>device events</key>
                <array>
                    <string>scan</string>
                </array>
                <key>device type</key>
                <string>scanner</string>
                <key>idProduct</key>
                <integer>18455</integer>
                <key>idVendor</key>
                <integer>7628</integer>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
```

and Info.plist. I tried to add also add com.apple.developer.driverkit.transport.usb key with Vendor ID into entitlemens file, but no changes, the scanner is not shown in ImageCapture.app.